# What is alternate for rawtype declaration of List

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-8

I have a piece of code where I am calling a dao method and returning a list of diff objects depending on the result of the call.
The caller method returns the List depending on the result of the query.
The called method has declaration in rawtype like below.
The code is compiling fine, but getting a runtime error for certain queries when there is casting problem.

```
public List loadTransformedObjectWithNativeSQL(String paramString, Map paramMap, Object[] paramArrayOfObject, Class paramClass)
  { .......
```

The caller method is like below :

```
public List<ModelData> getModelQuestionaire(Map<String, Object> params) {

        String sql = getSql("getModelQuestionaire");

        Object[] values = new Object[2];
        values[0] = params.get("contractType");
        values[1] = params.get("modelVerID");

        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("quesID", StringType.INSTANCE);
        map.put("questionaire", StringType.INSTANCE);
        map.put("quesValueType", StringType.INSTANCE);
        map.put("valueID", StringType.INSTANCE);
        map.put("quesValue", StringType.INSTANCE);
        map.put("noOfAnswer", StringType.INSTANCE);
        map.put("modelQuesValueID", StringType.INSTANCE);

        return loadTransformedObjectWithNativeSQL(sql, map, values, ModelData.class);
    }
```

Now for this method I am returning ModelData class..for other methods I might return some other class.

What will be the best way to typesafe the called method.
I have tried `List<?>` but getting compile errors.

If I only keep List, I am getting this runtime error :

```
 17:18:58,121 INFO  [stdout] (default task-21) *************SQLQuery[OBJ]*****************Select q.ques_id quesid,q.question questionaire ,q.value_typ quesValueType,a.value_id valueID,a.question_value quesValue,(select count(1) from cost_ques_value c where c.ques_id=q.ques_id) noOfAnswer, nvl(v.value_id,'0') modelQuesValueID from cost_questionaire q,cost_ques_value a, cost_mdl_ver_t_c_ques_value v where q.ques_id=a.ques_id and q.Category_level=? and q.ques_id = v.ques_id(+) and v.mdl_ver_id(+)=? and q.rec_status_ind=1 and a.rec_status_ind=1 order by q.ques_id
17:18:58,259 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21) java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ge.energy.common.data.config.ModelData cannot be cast to java.util.Map
17:18:58,261 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessMapImpl$SetterImpl.set(PropertyAccessMapImpl.java:102)
17:18:58,261 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:78)
17:18:58,262 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.hibernate.hql.internal.HolderInstantiator.instantiate(HolderInstantiator.java:85)
17:18:58,262 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.getResultList(CustomLoader.java:430)
17:18:58,262 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507)
17:18:58,262 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)
17:18:58,263 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:335)
17:18:58,263 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2200)
17:18:58,263 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1016)
17:18:58,264 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:152)
17:18:58,264 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
17:18:58,264 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
17:18:58,265 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.dao.BaseDao.loadTransformedObjectWithNativeSQL(BaseDao.java:228)
17:18:58,265 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.dao.config.ConfigConfigDaoImpl.getModelQuestionaire(ConfigConfigDaoImpl.java:2415)
17:18:58,266 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
17:18:58,267 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
17:18:58,268 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
17:18:58,268 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
17:18:58,268 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338)
17:18:58,269 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
17:18:58,269 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
17:18:58,270 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
17:18:58,271 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
17:18:58,271 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
17:18:58,271 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
17:18:58,271 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.getModelQuestionaire(Unknown Source)
17:18:58,272 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.services.config.ModelConfigServiceImpl.getModelQuestionaire(ModelConfigServiceImpl.java:301)
17:18:58,272 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
17:18:58,273 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
17:18:58,274 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
17:18:58,274 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
17:18:58,274 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338)
17:18:58,275 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:206)
17:18:58,276 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.getModelQuestionaire(Unknown Source)
17:18:58,276 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.services.config.ModelConfigSvcImpl.getModelQuestionaire(ModelConfigSvcImpl.java:1872)
17:18:58,276 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.cmd.config.model.LoadModelQuestionaireCmd.perform(LoadModelQuestionaireCmd.java:325)
17:18:58,278 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.cmd.config.model.LoadModelQuestionaireCmd$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$346f0b5b.invoke(<generated>)
17:18:58,278 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
17:18:58,278 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
17:18:58,278 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
17:18:58,279 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
17:18:58,279 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
17:18:58,279 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
17:18:58,279 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
17:18:58,279 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.cmd.config.model.LoadModelQuestionaireCmd$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7bf6e8d7.perform(<generated>)
17:18:58,280 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.controller.config.model.ModelController.modifyModelOpenModel(ModelController.java:438)
17:18:58,280 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.controller.config.model.ModelController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9a0181ee.invoke(<generated>)
17:18:58,280 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
17:18:58,280 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
17:18:58,280 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
17:18:58,281 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
17:18:58,281 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.aspect.ExceptionAspectHandler.handleControllerExceptionsWithAroundReturnString(ExceptionAspectHandler.java:45)
17:18:58,281 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
17:18:58,281 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
17:18:58,282 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
17:18:58,282 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
17:18:58,282 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:643)
17:18:58,282 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:632)
17:18:58,283 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
17:18:58,283 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
17:18:58,283 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
17:18:58,283 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
17:18:58,284 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
17:18:58,284 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.controller.config.model.ModelController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2add3965.modifyModelOpenModel(<generated>)
17:18:58,285 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
17:18:58,285 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
17:18:58,285 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
17:18:58,285 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
17:18:58,285 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
17:18:58,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
17:18:58,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
17:18:58,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
17:18:58,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
17:18:58,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
17:18:58,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
17:18:58,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
17:18:58,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
17:18:58,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
17:18:58,288 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
17:18:58,289 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
17:18:58,290 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
17:18:58,290 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
17:18:58,290 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
17:18:58,290 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
17:18:58,291 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
17:18:58,291 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
17:18:58,294 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
17:18:58,295 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
17:18:58,295 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
17:18:58,296 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
17:18:58,297 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
17:18:58,297 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
17:18:58,297 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
17:18:58,298 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
17:18:58,298 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
17:18:58,298 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
17:18:58,298 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
17:18:58,298 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
17:18:58,299 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
17:18:58,299 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
17:18:58,299 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
17:18:58,299 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
17:18:58,299 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
17:18:58,299 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
17:18:58,300 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
17:18:58,300 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
17:18:58,300 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
17:18:58,300 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
17:18:58,300 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
17:18:58,300 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
17:18:58,301 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
17:18:58,306 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
17:18:58,307 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
17:18:58,308 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
17:18:58,308 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
17:18:58,308 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
17:18:58,309 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
17:18:58,309 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
17:18:58,309 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
17:18:58,309 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17:18:58,311 ERROR [com.gee.gecs.cosmos.aspect.ICAMExceptionHandler] (default task-21) A UndeclaredThrowableException has occured in the application: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.controller.config.model.ModelController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2add3965.modifyModelOpenModel(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitia
```

If I change the `List` to `List<?>` I am getting compile time error:

```
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<capture#55-of ?> to 
 List<ModelData>
```

What is the best way to resolve this.I have multiple methods calling this

```
public List loadTransformedObjectWithNativeSQL(String paramString, Map paramMap, Object[] paramArrayOfObject, Class paramClass)
  {
    Object localObject = null;
    NativeQuery localNativeQuery = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createNativeQuery(paramString);
    Iterator localIterator = paramMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (localIterator.hasNext())
    {
      Map.Entry localEntry = (Map.Entry)localIterator.next();
      String str = (String)localEntry.getKey();
      Type localType = (Type)localEntry.getValue();
      localNativeQuery.addScalar(str, localType);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= paramArrayOfObject.length; i++) {
        localNativeQuery.setParameter(i, paramArrayOfObject[(i - 1)]);
      }
    System.out.println("*************SQLQuery[OBJ]*****************" +localNativeQuery.getQueryString());
    localNativeQuery.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(paramClass));
    return localNativeQuery.getResultList();
  }
```

Comment: `List` is really the right thing, given what you've told us... If not all of them return List types, you'll need to give us more info, or possibly the compile error and relevant code.

Comment: I have given the full code..pls guide

Answer (score 0):

Copy the List.  Doing so will guarantee the type safety of the list, since casting throws an exception at runtime if it is incorrect:

```
List<?> untypedData = (List<?>)
    loadTransformedObjectWithNativeSQL(sql, map, values, ModelData.class);

List<ModelData> modelData = new ArrayList<>(untypedData.size());
for (Object datum : untypedData) {
    modelData.add((ModelData) datum);
}

return modelData;
```

This might seem wasteful, but it’s not.  You’re only copying references.  If we pessimistically assume a reference is 256 bytes (it’s probably smaller than that), copying 4,000 of them will use 1 MB of memory.

Comment: Still getting the same error at runtime..even after change of code

Comment: The stack trace you’ve shown in your question suggests that the problem lies elsewhere, as the `getModelQuestionaire` method does not appear in the stack trace at all.  If there is more to the stack trace, please add it to your question.

Comment: I have tried to give almost complete stacktrace..and getModelQuestionaire is there in the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved..In my code there was problem with mapping between ModelData class items - questinaire and the query result columns. Once that is fixed, this error is gone.